# How can i test with PEST (and Laravel) that Model::shouldBeStrict is called inside the AppServiceProvider

Tags: laravel, testing, pest

I  want to test, that `Model::shouldBeStrict` is called inside the `AppServiceProvider`.

I tried:

```php
it('will use Model::shouldBeStrict', function () {
    $user = User::factory()->create();
    $a = $user->notExistingAttribute;
})->throws(Exception::class);
```

but no exception is thrown.

What can I do to test it?

Comment: https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/10.x/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php#L408 that method sets some flags in the service provider. I can't test now but can you check those flags, like https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/534872c3fdc6dcea2bd3728b44f9302b952e5cab/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php#L2173

Comment: Yes - that should work. i found a   public static function preventsLazyLoading() and i try to use these functions. Thank you very much!